# How to implement Beholder (Tensorboard plugin) for Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to implement the [Beholder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/beholder) plugin from Tensorboard into a simple CNN code (I am a beginner at Tensorflow), but I am not sure where to put the `visualizer.update(session=session)`.
At the beginning I have:

```
from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import Beholder
LOG_DIRECTORY='/tmp/tensorflow_logs'
visualizer = Beholder(logdir=LOG_DIRECTORY)
```

I train my model like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(253,27,3))) 
.
.
.
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Where should I put the `visualizer.update(session=session)` and what else should I put in my code, as for now it says No Beholder data was found. Thank you!

Comment: Did u find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be appropriate to create a [custom Keras callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_callback), so that you can call `visualizer.update(session=session)` at the end of each epoch (or whenever you want). Here is an example showing how such callback could look like:

```
from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import Beholder
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
import keras

LOG_DIRECTORY='/tmp/tensorflow_logs'


class BeholderCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, tensor, logdir=LOG_DIRECTORY, sess=None):
        self.visualizer = Beholder(logdir=logdir)
        self.sess = sess
        if sess is None:
            self.sess = K.get_session()
        self.tensor = tensor

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        frame = self.sess.run(self.tensor)  # depending on the tensor, this might require a feed_dict
        self.visualizer.update(
            session=self.sess,
            frame=frame
        )
```

Then, after defining your model, instantiate the callback and pass it to [model.fit](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit):

```
# Define your Keras model
# ...

# Prepare callback
sess = K.get_session() 
beholder_callback = BeholderCallback(your_tensor, sess=sess)

# Fit data into model and pass callback to model.fit
model.fit(x=x_train,
          y=y_train,
          callbacks=[beholder_callback])
```

You could also use the argument `arrays` of `visualizer.update` in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify on how to get a value for "frame" within the keras framework? (also array) I've been having trouble with TF wanting a TF tensor, and I am only able to provide it with strings (names) or Keras layers....

Comment: You could probably get the value for "frame" by running `sess.run(your_tensor)`, where `your_tensor` is the TF tensor that you want to monitor. I have updated the code to show how this might look like